# Overriding hashCode() when overriding equals()

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Java, why must equals() and hashCode() be consistent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678205/in-java-why-must-equals-and-hashcode-be-consistent)

I read that one should always hascode() when overriding equals().

Can anyone give a practical example of why it might be wrong otherwise? 
i.e. Problems that might arise when overriding equals() but not hashCode().

Is it necessary to write a robust hasCode() function whenever we override equals()? Or a trivial implementation is enough?

For example,

A poor implementation such as the below is good enough to satisfy the contract between     equals() & hashCode()?

```
public int hashCode() {
   return 91;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Comment: @Blam Yes, I see that all the values are going to be in a single hash bucket. If we exclude the performance, is there any other problem with that? Or more precisely, is it going to break the program functionality-wise under any conditions?

Comment: It will not break anything to my knowledge.  I trust you are not going to use this in a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`equals()` and `hashCode()` are used conjunctively in certain collections, such as `HashSet` and `HashMap`, so you have to make sure that if you use these collections, you override `hashCode` according to the contract.

If you don't override `hashCode` at all, then you'll have problems with `HashSet` and `HashMap`. In particular, two objects that are "equal" may be put in different hash buckets even though they should be equal.

If you do override `hashCode`, but do so poorly, then you'll have performance issues. All your entries for `HashSet` and `HashMap` will be put into the same bucket, and you'll lose the O(1) performance and have O(n) instead. This is because the data structure essentially becomes a linearly-checked linked list.

As for breaking programs outside of these conditions, it's not likely, but you never know when an API (especially in 3rd-party libraries) is going to depend on this contract. The contract is upheld for objects that *don't* implement either of them, so it's conceivable that a library may depend on this somewhere without using hash buckets.

In any case, implementing a good `hashCode` is easy, especially if you're using an IDE. Eclipse and Netbeans both have the ability to generate `equals` and `hashCode` for you in a way that all contracts are followed, including the inverse rules of `equals` (the assertion that `a.equals(b) == b.equals(a)`). All you need to do is select the fields you want to be included and go.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think, you have given a fair explanation when it might be a problem with a poor implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Both `equals` and `hashcode` are based on the principle of object's unicity. If `equals` returns `true` the hashcode of both objects must be the same, otherwise hash based structures and algorithms could have undefined results.

Think of a hash based structure such as a `HashMap`. `hashcode` will be invoked as a base to get the key's reference, not `equals`, making it impossible in most cases to find the key. Also, a poor implementation of `hashcode` will create collisions (multiple objects with the same `hashcode`, which one is the "correct" one?) that affect performance.

IMHO, overriding `equals` OR `hashcode` (instead of overriding both) should be considered a code smell or, at least, a potential bugs source. That is, unless you're 100% sure it won't affect your code sooner or later (when are we so sure anyway?).

Note: There are various libraries that provide support for this by having `equals` and `hashcode` builders, like [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) with `HashcodeBuilder` and `EqualsBuilder`.

Comment: In Java 7, there's the [`Objects`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) class with its hashing methods as well.

Comment: @Brian Indeed! I'm so used to Apache Commons that I forgot that one ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code that illustrates a bug you can introduce by not implementing hashCode(): Set.contains() will first check the hashCode() of an object, and then check .equals(). So, if you don't implement both, .contains() will not behave in an intuitive way:

```
public class ContainsProblem {

// define a class that implements equals, without implementing hashcode
class Car {
    private String name;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Car)) return false;
        Car car = (Car) o;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(car.name) : car.name != null) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public String getName() {return name;}

    public Car(String name) { this.name = name;}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ContainsProblem oc = new ContainsProblem();

    ContainsProblem.Car ford = oc.new Car("ford");
    ContainsProblem.Car chevy = oc.new Car("chevy");
    ContainsProblem.Car anotherFord = oc.new Car("ford");
    Set cars = Sets.newHashSet(ford,chevy);

    // if the set of cars contains a ford, a ford is equal to another ford, shouldn't
    // the set return the same thing for both fords? without hashCode(), it won't:
    if (cars.contains(ford) && ford.equals(anotherFord) && !cars.contains(anotherFord)) {
        System.out.println("oh noes, why don't we have a ford? isn't this a bug?");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your trivial implementation is correct, but would kill the performance of hash-based collections.

The default implementation (provided by `Object`) would break the contract if two different instances of your class compared equal.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java" Chapter 3 "Methods Common to All Objects". Nobody can explaing better than him. He He led the design and implementation of numerous Java platform features.