# How to evaluate list in java equality of two object

Tags: java

I have a arrayList and i want use contains(Thing o) method to check equality of this two object and I override the equals() method in Thing class but this is not work when I call contains method!
this is my thing class:

```
public class Thing{

private int id;

//getter setter

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(!(o instanceof Thing))
        return false;
    if(id == ((Thing)o).getId())
        return true;
    return false;
}
}
```

is it necessary to override the hashCode() method too? if yes how to override it?

Comment: Can you show how you used `contains` method? And yes, you should always override both `equals` and `hashcode` when you override one of them.

Comment: Overriding hashcode is a good practice but won't help in your case. To override it you can simply `return id;`…

Comment: `dblist` is List<Thing> and I have a Thing object with `nlo` name.
     `if(dblist.contains(nlo)){
     //do something
     }`

Comment: Post an SSCCE reproducing the problem.

Comment: nlo is a name of variable? it can contain Thing object with any id.

Comment: `nlo` has the same `id` with one of the objects in `dblist`

Comment: Add `if (o == null) { return false; }` to the beginning of your `equals()` method. Also don't forget about `hashCode()` as said. But your code should work even without that things, try iterating over your list and campare ids of every element with your `nlo`, error is definetly somewhere else

Comment: @SpongeBobFan: the null case is already handled by instanceof, which will always return false if the object is null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should override `hashCode`. The `ArrayList` class doesn't use the `hashCode` method so it's not necessary *now*, but if at any point you are going to use your class with `HashMap`, `HashSet`, or any other collection that does use `hashCode`, the program will break because [`hashCode` and `equals` are not consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678205/in-java-why-must-equals-and-hashcode-be-consistent).

A simple implementation of hashCode for this case could be:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is essential to override hashCode() whenever u override equals :

- If you do not overrode HashCode(), the default behaviour from the
  "Object" class is to give each object a unique hashCode.
- This unique hashCode would mean two different object instances unless
  you override the hashCode() to give the same value.

  public int hashCode(){
  return this.id;
  }

you dont have to write this manually when you are using Eclipse.:)
RightCLick on the java file opened -->Source-->Generate HashCode() and equals()

Answer (score 1):

In case you override equals() you should always override hashCode() too. By using Eclipse IDE you simply can generate that methods for you. Menu -> Source -> Generate hashCode() and equals()