# How do I compare two objects in Java where the expected objects properties are dynamic

Tags: java, compare, cucumber, comparator, gherkin

I'm looking for a way to compare objects in Java based on dynamic properties written in Cucumber/Gherkin format.

Has anyone implemented anything like this or knows of a framework which can achieve this?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

*cucumber.feature*

```
Feature: Cucumber Feature 1

  Scenario: Test 1
    Given my micro-service is up and running
    When I submit something to my API
    Then I verify the response object looks like this:
      | property1 | value1 |
      | property3 | value3 |
      | property5 | value5 |
```

*StepDefinitions.java*

```
public class StepDefinitions {

    private ResponseObject storedResponseObject;

    @Given("^my micro-service is up and running$")
    public void given() throws Throwable {
        ...
    }

    @When("^I submit something to my API$")
    public void when() throws Throwable {
        storedResponseObject = postSomethingToAPI();
    }

    @Then("^I verify the response object looks like this:$")
    public void then(Map<String, String> gherkinMap) throws Throwable {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ResponseObject expectedResponseObject = objectMapper.convertValue(gherkinMap, ResponseObject.class);
        ResponseObject actualResponseObject = storedResponseObject;
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedResponseObject, actualResponseObject);
    }
}
```

*ResponseObject.java*

```
public class ResponseObject {

    private String property1;
    private String property2;
    private String property3;
    private String property4;
    private String property5;

    public String getProperty1() {
        return property1;
    }

    public void setProperty1(String property1) {
        this.property1 = property1;
    }

    public String getProperty2() {
        return property2;
    }

    public void setProperty2(String property2) {
        this.property2 = property2;
    }

    public String getProperty3() {
        return property3;
    }

    public void setProperty3(String property3) {
        this.property3 = property3;
    }

    public String getProperty4() {
        return property4;
    }

    public void setProperty4(String property4) {
        this.property4 = property4;
    }

    public String getProperty5() {
        return property5;
    }

    public void setProperty5(String property5) {
        this.property5 = property5;
    }
}
```

Note - The Assert.assertEquals() clearly isn't going to work.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Ben :)

Comment: Maybe using a dictionary instead of generic properties would be a good option. I leave you an example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543457/how-do-you-create-a-dictionary-in-java

Comment: Some kind of Reflection comparer (e.g. org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals).  But it might actually be more useful to compare JSON output.

Answer (score 1):

Override `equals` method in `ResponseObject`. In overrided method realize comparing logic.

**EDIT**

As @Wietlol noticed, override `hashcode` method too. More about this you can read here [In Java, why must equals() and hashCode() be consistent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678205/in-java-why-must-equals-and-hashcode-be-consistent)

Comment: Also make sure to override the hashCode() method... and to make equals() take in an object